# I want to check for different conditions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to check for a condition in mongo DB.

If `"availability_detail.daily_schedule"` exists in a database record, then I want to check for `"availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time": { $lte: add_time }`, otherwise I want to check it for `"availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time": { $lte: "00:00" }`

In db, my record is saved as  follows :

```
"availability_detail" : {
    "daily_schedule" : {
      "start_time" : "03:00",
      "end_time" : "04:00"
    },
    "on_days" : [ 
        "Monday", 
        "Tuesday", 
        "Wednesday", 
        "Thursday", 
        "Friday", 
        "Saturday", 
        "Sunday"
    ],
}
```

OR

```
"availability_detail" : {
    // Here, the daily_schedule does not exist
    "on_days" : [ 
        "Monday", 
        "Tuesday", 
        "Wednesday", 
        "Thursday", 
        "Friday", 
        "Saturday", 
        "Sunday"
    ],
}
```

Can anyone help me achieve this? I am new to mongoDb and I could not find any solution for it.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the second condition doesn't make sense to me.  If `availability_detail.daily_schedule` doesn't exist, why would you try to check the value of an element beneath it?

Comment: @DaveCosta, I have other condition that if all days of the week are available, it means place is available for 24 hours  every day. otherwise, there is time limit for each day. So,  I want to find an available place on the basis of time.

Comment: I think that if the daily_schedule doesn't exist, you don't need to check the time at all.  In pseudo-code, I think you want: `daily_schedule doesn't exist OR ( requested_time >= start_time AND requested_time <= end_time)`  It would probably take me hours to figure out how to write this in Mongo's absurd query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function which can do this in MongoDB cause issue with your schema, In general you can actually do this : `"availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time": { $eq: "00:00" }` but not this `"availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time": { $lte: "00:00" }` cause string to string comparison can be done `"00:00" == "00:00"` or `"00:00" !== "00:00"` but when it comes to greater than or less than operators `"00:00" >= "00:00"` or `"00:00" =< "00:00"` doesn't work well in database, So best is to save those as type **Int** in documents.

As you've already stored data in `"00:00"` format, then you need to convert those into integers like `0` using [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) & compare against an integer input.

**Query 1 :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [{"availability_detail.daily_schedule": {$exists: false}},
          {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [ 
                 {$toInt: 
                   {
                    $concat: [
                      {$substr: [ "$availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time",0,2]},
                      {$substr: [ "$availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time",3,4]}
                     ] 
                   }
                 },
                0 /** Input 0 for "00:00" or 310 for "03:10" or 1830 for "18:30" */
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0BZxdKVeVR4)

**Query 2 :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [{"availability_detail.daily_schedule": {$exists: false}},
        {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [
                {
                  $toInt: {
                    $concat: [
                      {
                        $arrayElemAt: [{$split: ["$availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time",":"]},0]
                      },
                      {
                        $arrayElemAt: [{$split: ["$availability_detail.daily_schedule.start_time",":"]},1]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                0 /** Input 0 for "00:00" or 310 for "03:10" or 1830 for "18:30" */
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Iw6YeNGLdig)